# How do you create/compile a directive via a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building out a Modal factory and am getting constantly stumped on issues with `$compile`. I'm trying to use a factory to dynamically add a Modal directive to the page.

The directive itself has some internal logic which allows it to open via publishing through an API service. It registers itself to the pub/sub service in its `postLink` like so:

```
postLink: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  api.subscribe(attrs.id, function(msg) {
    //magic happens here
   });
}
```

The factory creates and appends the directive like so:

```
angular.module('modal')
  .factory('ModalFactory', ['$compile', '$rootScope', 'Api', function($compile, $rootScope, api) {
    return function modalFactory(config) {
      var scope, element, html, id;

      init(); //run init so it's initialized on creation

      function activate() {
        api.publish(id, 'activate');
      }

      function init() {
        //checks if initialized already
        //uses assembleDirective to get the html string and scope

        angular.element(document.body).append($compile(html)(scope)); //this is the important line of code
      }


     function assembleDirective() {
      //an html string is assembled here and stored into html. uses html from config

      //rootscope is used to create a new scope (unless provided in config) 
     }     

      return {
        activate: activate,
        deactivate: deactivate
      }
    }

}]);
```

Here's the issue, whenever I run this logic in the controller, like so:

```
//imagine we're in a controller
var myModal = new ModalFactory({ }); //create empty modal
myModal.activate(); //fails
```

The problem? When I run `myModal.activate()`, for some reason, the directive hasn't run any of its internal linking logic yet. I console.logged out the process and the activate method runs before the directive itself runs link. Which just blows my mind because I thought I've just compiled it and added to the DOM (and when I think of compiling, I'm thinking of the pre/post link functions running)

When I console logged `$compile(html)(scope)`, it returns a jQLite element with *everything* compiled which makes me think it's working correctly. But, when I got the actual piece of DOM out of the jQLite object (via just doing `[0]` at the end), I got a DOM representation of my original HTML string, uncompiled.

When I attached a separate method to the controller which runs `myModal.activate()` on click, the directive has already run its link method and the modal gets activated.

Comment: How does your api service work? How do you call init? Are you in the digest cycle?

Comment: The API is a simple pub/sub system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone perusing this question, I did finally come up with an answer, first Peter's suggestion helped immensely (compiling AFTER the element is appended).

What I ended up doing was setting a property on the scope before compiling. That property fired an `init` function in the Modal in the postLink thus the async nature of `$compile` didn't matter in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that moving angular elements around the DOM screws with Angulars internals. The safe way to do what you're doing is to append it first, then compile. The time lapse between the two will be minor. Do you encounter issues if you change your code like this?

```
  function init() {
    //checks if initialized already
    //uses assembleDirective to get the html string and scope
    var modalElt = angular.element(document.body).append(html);
    $compile(modalElt)(scope);
  }
```

Perhaps review the code in angular-modal by Brian Ford:

https://github.com/btford/angular-modal/blob/master/modal.js

Look for the line with $compile

Comment: So I tried your solution and that resulted in Chrome crashing the tab. I think that what you're suggesting will compile the entire body and perhaps get stuck in an infinite loop.

I checked out the angular-modal code and saw that instead of compiling the entire body of the document, he compiled what he appended after appending it, if that makes sense. That solution still didn't work as I think that $compile is async and that's where I'm running into a wall.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the append function just returned the HTML of the modal - that's what I intended. Glad it helped you anyway. Shouldn't try to be cute like that